Why does my ParseHeaders function fail to read NT/Optional headers from a PE file?
The purpose of the program is to print the areas of a portable executable that I want, including the IAT offset and EAT offset and print all imported functions with their addresses and module.
The problem I'm getting seems to be with the function I made that converts RVAs to offsets (which is needed for locating something in a PE file), but it could be something else.
The output of my program is:
        [>] Number of Sections: 10
        [>] Size of Optional Header: 240
        [>] File is an EXE
        [>] Architecture: x64
        [>] Image Base: 0x0000000140000000
        [>] Image Size: 0x00026000
        [>] Section Alignment: 0x00001000
        [>] File Alignment: 0x00000200
        [>] Subsystem: 0x0003
        [>] Number of Data Directories: 16
        [>] Size of Stack Reserve: 0x0000000000100000 bytes
        [>] Size of Stack Commit: 0x0000000000001000 bytes
        [>] Size of Heap Reserve: 0x0000000000100000 bytes
        [>] Size of Heap Commit: 0x0000000000001000 bytes
Unknown optional header size
Failed to read NT headers

So yeah im failing to read optional headers and nt headers
Here's the function I use for rva to file offsets:
uint32_t rva_to_offset(uint32_t rva, IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* sections, int numberOfSections) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
        uint32_t sectionStartRVA = sections[i].VirtualAddress;
        uint32_t sectionEndRVA = sectionStartRVA + sections[i].Misc.VirtualSize;

        if (rva >= sectionStartRVA && rva < sectionEndRVA) {
            // calculate and return the offset
            uint32_t offset = sections[i].PointerToRawData + (rva - sectionStartRVA);
            printf("RVA 0x%08X maps to offset 0x%08X in section %d\n", rva, offset, i);
            return offset;
        }
    }
    return 0xFFFFFFFF; // err
}

Then parse headers:
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ParseHeaders(FILE* pefile, OUT uint16_t* architecture) {
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER DOSHeader;

    if (fread(&DOSHeader, sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER), 1, pefile) != 1) {
        printf("Failed to read DOS header \n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Move the file pointer to the NT headers location
    if (fseek(pefile, DOSHeader.e_lfanew, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to seek to NT headers \n");
        return NULL;
    }

    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)malloc(sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));

    if (NtHeaders == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory for NT headers \n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (fread(NtHeaders, sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS), 1, pefile) != 1) {
        printf("Failed to read NT headers \n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Check the signature
    if (NtHeaders->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) {
        printf("Invalid NT headers signature \n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // File header
    IMAGE_FILE_HEADER* FileHeader = &NtHeaders->FileHeader;
    printf("\t[>] Number of Sections: %u\n", FileHeader->NumberOfSections);
    printf("\t[>] Size of Optional Header: %u\n", FileHeader->SizeOfOptionalHeader);

    // Check if DLL or EXE
    if (FileHeader->Characteristics & IMAGE_FILE_DLL) {
        printf("\t[>] File is a DLL \n");
    }
    if (FileHeader->Characteristics & IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE) {
        printf("\t[>] File is an EXE \n");
    }

    if (NtHeaders->OptionalHeader.OptionalHeader32.Magic == IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR32_MAGIC) {
        printf("\t[>] Architecture: x86 \n");
        *architecture = IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR32_MAGIC;

        // Access 32-bit optional header fields
        i print  parsed PE stuff here, i wont include it bc its long
    }
    else if (NtHeaders->OptionalHeader.OptionalHeader64.Magic == IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC) {
        printf("\t[>] Architecture: x64 \n");
        *architecture = IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC;

        // Access 64-bit optional header fields
        i print parsed PE stuff here, i wont include it bc its long
    }
    else {
        printf("\t[>] Architecture: ?");
        *architecture = 0;
        free(NtHeaders);
        return NULL;
    }

    return NtHeaders;
}

I use the rva to offset function for parsing sections ("Unknown optional header size" occurs here):
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER ParseSections(FILE* pefile, IN IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* NtHeaders) {

    // Calculate offset from the start of the file
    size_t sizeOfHeaders = 0;
    if (NtHeaders->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader == sizeof(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32)) {
        sizeOfHeaders = NtHeaders->OptionalHeader.OptionalHeader32.SizeOfHeaders;
    }
    else if (NtHeaders->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader == sizeof(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64)) {
        sizeOfHeaders = NtHeaders->OptionalHeader.OptionalHeader64.SizeOfHeaders;
    }
    else {
        printf("Unknown optional header size \n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Calculate the offset to the section headers
    if (fseek(pefile, sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER) + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS) + sizeOfHeaders, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to seek to section headers \n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for section headers
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER SectionHeaders = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)malloc(NtHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER));
    if (SectionHeaders == NULL) {
        printf("Allocation failed (section headers) \n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Read section headers from the file
    size_t readCount = fread(SectionHeaders, sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER), NtHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections, pefile);
    if (readCount != NtHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections) {
        printf("Failed to read section headers \n");
        free(SectionHeaders);
        return NULL;
    }

    return SectionHeaders;
}

Parsing IAT ("Failed to read NT headers" occurs here)
void ParseIAT(FILE* pefile, uint16_t architecture) {
    if (!pefile) {
        printf("Invalid PE file\n");
        return;
    }

    if (architecture != IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC) {
        printf("Error: Not x64 but trying to parse x64.\n");
        return;
    }

    // Seek to the start of the NT headers to read them properly
    fseek(pefile, 0, SEEK_SET);

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeaders;
    if (fread(&NtHeaders, sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS), 1, pefile) != 1) {
        printf("Failed to read NT headers \n");
        return;
    }

    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER SectionHeaders = ParseSections(pefile, &NtHeaders);
    if (SectionHeaders == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to parse sections \n");
        return;
    }

    IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 OptionalHeader64 = NtHeaders.OptionalHeader.OptionalHeader64;

    // Get import directory RVA
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ImportDirectory = OptionalHeader64.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];
    uint32_t ImportDirectoryRVA = ImportDirectory.VirtualAddress;
    uint32_t ImportDirectorySize = ImportDirectory.Size;

    if (ImportDirectoryRVA == 0) {
        printf("No import directory \n");
        return;
    }

    printf("\t[>] Import Directory Address: 0x%08X - Size: 0x%08X\n\n", ImportDirectoryRVA, ImportDirectorySize);

    // Convert import directory RVA to a file offset
    uint32_t ImportDirectoryOffset = rva_to_offset(ImportDirectoryRVA, SectionHeaders, NtHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

    if (ImportDirectoryOffset == 0xFFFFFFFF) {
        printf("Invalid import directory offset\n");
        return;
    }

    // Seek to the import directory
    if (fseek(pefile, ImportDirectoryOffset, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to seek to import directory\n");
        return;
    }

    IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR ImportDescriptor;
    while (fread(&ImportDescriptor, sizeof(ImportDescriptor), 1, pefile) == 1) {

        if (ImportDescriptor.Name == 0) {
            break; // end of descriptors
        }

        // Get module name
        uint32_t moduleNameRVA = ImportDescriptor.Name;
        uint32_t moduleNameOffset = rva_to_offset(moduleNameRVA, SectionHeaders, NtHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

        if (moduleNameOffset == 0xFFFFFFFF) {
            printf("Invalid module name offset\n");
            return;
        }

        char moduleName[256];

        fseek(pefile, moduleNameOffset, SEEK_SET);

        if (fread(moduleName, 1, sizeof(moduleName) - 1, pefile) <= 0) {
            printf("Failed to read module name\n");
            return;
        }

        moduleName[sizeof(moduleName) - 1] = '\0';

        printf("[+] Module: %s\n", moduleName);

        uint32_t iatRVA = ImportDescriptor.FirstThunk;
        uint32_t iatOffset = rva_to_offset(iatRVA, SectionHeaders, NtHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

        if (iatOffset == 0xFFFFFFFF) {
            printf("Invalid IAT offset\n");
            return;
        }

        if (fseek(pefile, iatOffset, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
            printf("Failed to seek IAT offset\n");
            return;
        }

        // Read and print addresses to all functions in this module's IAT
        uint32_t iatEntry;
        printf("[+] Import Address Table Offset: 0x%08X\n", iatOffset);

        while (fread(&iatEntry, sizeof(iatEntry), 1, pefile) == 1) {
            if (iatEntry == 0) {
                break; // end of entries
            }

            printf("\t[>] Function Address: 0x%08X ", iatEntry);

            if (iatEntry & 0x80000000) {
                uint16_t ordinal = (uint16_t)(iatEntry & 0xFFFF); // extract ordinal
                printf("\t\t[>] Function imported by ordinal: %u\n", ordinal);
            }
            else {
                uint32_t functionNameOffset = rva_to_offset(iatEntry, SectionHeaders, NtHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

                if (functionNameOffset == 0xFFFFFFFF) {
                    printf("Invalid function name offset\n");
                    return;
                }

                fseek(pefile, functionNameOffset, SEEK_SET);

                IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME functionName;
                if (fread(&functionName, sizeof(functionName), 1, pefile) != 1) {
                    printf("Failed to read function name\n");
                    return;
                }

                printf("\t\t[>] Name: %s\n", functionName.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}

how i call them main:
    PE pe;
    pe.FilePath = argv[1];
    
    FILE* pefile = fopen(pe.FilePath, "rb");
    
    uint16_t architecture;

    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeaders = ParseHeaders(pefile, &architecture);

    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER SectionHeaders = ParseSections(pefile, NtHeaders);

    // PE32+ (x64)
    if (architecture == IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC) {
        ParseEAT(pefile, architecture);
        ParseIAT(pefile, architecture);
    }

i apologize for lot of code i just can't figure out what the issue is

SizeOfOptionalHeader is variable
